# Error saying 'Your connection is not private' when running API project

Tags: c#, security, browser, visual-studio-2022

When I started my C# API project in VS2022, I got an error 'Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified, and the default developer certificate could not be found or is out of date.' After running Certmgr.mgc I saw that my Personal>Certificates were out of date so I deleted them and ran `dotnet dev-certs https -t` followed by `dotnet dev-certs https --clean`.

Then my Chrome browser ran but with this error:

> 'Your connection is not private
> Attackers might be trying to steal your information from localhost (for example, passwords, messages or credit cards).'

[image]

I've tried running the dotnet commands again in reverse order, I've also tried toggling the 'Always use secure connections' in my browser settings but I can't get rid of this error. I'm sure others will have had this error so can someone please help as I can't get any work done until my browser is working properly.

Answer (score -1):

You are running this on localhost and that's why getting this error, just go to your Properties folder of your project and open launchSetting.json right there and change application urls from 'https' to 'http'